Can we simplify the integral $\int_0^\infty\cdots\int_0^\infty f\left(\sum_{i=1}^ns_i\right)g\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_is_i\right)ds_n\cdots ds_1$?
How can we simplify the integral $$I:=\int_0^\infty\cdots\int_0^\infty f\left(\sum_{i=1}^ns_i\right)g\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_is_i\right){\rm d}s_n\cdots{\rm d}s_1,$$ where $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n>0$? If $f=1$, we should have $$I=\frac1{(n-1)!\prod_{i=1}^n\alpha_i}\int_0^\infty g(s)s^{n-1}\;{\rm d}s\tag1.$$ In particular, if $g=1$, then $$I=\frac1{(n-1)!}\int_0^\infty f(s)s^{n-1}\;{\rm d}s\tag2.$$ However, I fail to prove the general case, since I have no idea for a suitable substitution.
Motivation: I need to evaluate the expectation $\operatorname E\left[h(\sigma)\right]$, where $\sigma=\sum_{i=1}^n\tau_i$ is a sum of independent exponentially distributed random variables $\tau_i$ with parameter $\alpha_i$. If $\alpha_1=\cdots=\alpha_n$, then this expectation is equal to $\alpha_1^nI$ with $f(x)=e^{-\alpha_1x}h(x)$ and $g=1$. This way we see that $\sigma$ is gamma distributed with shape parameter $\alpha_1$ in that case. I try to generalize this result to the case, where the $\alpha_i$ are distinct. In that general case, the expectation is $\prod_{i=1}^n\alpha_iI$ with $f=h$ and $g(x)=e^{-x}$.
